# DNN get params in view are not available in edit

Tags: module, dotnetnuke-7

I am creating a dnn module. The content depends on the param in the url.

I want to be able to edit this content in the 'edit content' mode. However when i go to edit content the param in the url is no longer accessible because it is the parent document. How do i go about passing this value from the view.ascx to the edit.ascx?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try storing the param in cookies or localstorage. Then you should be able to access it. Of course the user will be able to modify it but you can do a check that the user has not modified it by storing a server side encryption or somthing like that.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround is to have a field where the user enters this parameter. But i know this isn't a very good solution. I am guessing that you will have to override the dotnetnuke core to do this (yes i know it sucks).

Answer (score 0):

I hope I am understanding the question properly.

To pass parameters from your View to Edit controls, you should first make sure they are registered properly in the module definition.  You default View should have an empty controlkey and your Edit should be registered with a control key, for example "addedit".

When creating a link between your view control and edit control, use the EditUrl() method of PortalModuleBase.  When passing a parameter, for example an id of the item you want to load into your edit control, you can pass them as arguments in the EditUr method.

Example (in my view.ascx.cs):

```
lnkEdit.NavigateUrl = EditUrl("id", "16", "addedit");
```

This will assign a module view link to the edit.ascx (assuming the controlkey in the definition is addedit) passing in a url parameter "id" with value 16.

See my DNN Module Views tutorial for a complete lesson on how to do DNN module views and navigation.

http://www.dnnhero.com/Premium/Tutorial/tabid/259/ArticleID/204/Introduction-and-Module-Definition-basics-in-DNN-Part-1-6.aspx